# Unable to get Postgresql to work with EF Core 2

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I'm trying to get an existing postgresql database to work with Entity Framework Core 2. I've incorporated Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design into my project. I've also set up the following in these files:

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext > (options =>
           options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database=DEFAULTDATABASE;"
  }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SLCore.Models
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
}
}
```

TodoItem.cs

```
namespace SLCore.Models
{
public class TodoItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
}
```

At this point it's my understanding I should migrate the database using

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

But I am not seeing how to open the dotnet CLI in VS 2017 Community, and I have tried it in powershell and it threw the following error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

I also tried

```
Scaffold-DBContext "Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;Password=1234;Database=DEFAULTDATABASE;" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -o Models
```

and I got the following error:

```
Scaffold-DBContext : The term 'Scaffold-DBContext' is not recognized as the         name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program.
```

After a lot of searching it seems like this should be the next step, but I'm stumped. Any suggestions?